Querying an old ArcGIS Service behind a proxy
I am in the need to use and analyse a map service that is behind a proxy. It works quite well in QGIS:
layer='1' url='http://govmap/arcgis/rest/services/MapCacheNational/MapServer/' urlprefix='https://ags.govmap.gov.il/proxy/proxy.ashx?'
The REST endpoint also indicates that it is possible to query the service:
{"currentVersion":10.41,"id":1,"name":"כתובת","type":"Feature Layer","description":"{ .... [],"canModifyLayer":true,"canScaleSymbols":false,"hasLabels":false,"capabilities":"Map,Query,Data","maxRecordCount":1000,"supportsStatistics":true,"supportsAdvancedQueries":true,"supportedQueryFormats":"JSON, AMF, geoJSON",...}
Yet nor the identify feature in QGIS works nor a direct URL like:
https://ags.govmap.gov.il/proxy/proxy.ashx/?http://govmap/arcgis/rest/services/MapCacheNational/MapServer/1?/query?where=1=1&returnCountOnly=true&outFields=*&f=json
The result is simply empty.
Unfortunately the service is not even addible in ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro... Any suggestions?
